# Place object in the end without pushing content

Tags: css

Im trying to add a dot in the end of a word or text. The content is inserted by the user so it can actually be different, which causes the problem. My best soulotion looks like this:

```css
.box{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
h3{
  text-align:Center;
}
.uglyDot{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:blueviolet;
}
#box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id = "box">
  <h3>A pretty long word here</h3>
  <div class="uglyDot"></div>
</div>
   <h3 id = "test">Small word</h3>

<div class="box" id = "box">
  <h3>Small word</h3>
  <div class="uglyDot"></div>
</div>
```

It is very close to what I'm trying to acheive. However in this example the star takes up space and pushes the word to the left. You can see that the two different "Small word" dont start from the same place. An option would be to set the uglyDot to position abolute but it doesn't work since the content can be different... Anyone got an idea how I solve this?

Fiddle to try: https://jsfiddle.net/fsbxoaj0/

Comment: Will there always be a dot regardless of what the user enters? If so, you may want to look into CSS pseudo elements.

Comment: Yepp there will always be a dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `::after` here as:

```
.uglyDot::after {
  content: ".";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: Center;
}

.uglyDot::after {
  content: ".";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box">
  <h3 class="uglyDot">A pretty long word here</h3>
</div>
<h3 id="test">Small word</h3>

<div class="box" id="box">
  <h3 class="uglyDot">Small word</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your dot as a DOM element for whatever reason, you should place it insde your h3 and add `display : inline-block` to it, otherwise I'd recommand using css pseudo-element ::after

```css
.box{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
h3{
  text-align:Center;
}
.uglyDot{
  display: inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:blueviolet;
}
#box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id = "box">
  <h3>A pretty long word here   <span class="uglyDot"></span></h3>
   
</div>
   <h3 id = "test">Small word</h3>

<div class="box" `enter code here`id = "box">
  <h3>Small word <span class="uglyDot"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Your soloution still pushes the Small word with the dot, compare where it starts from the Small word without the dot

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution with more lines but like Xanthous use inline-block, and use `margin-right:-10px;` to both Small word aligned

```css
.box{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.box h3{
  margin-right:-10px;
  justify-self:center;
  text-align:Center;
  border:1px solid black;
}
h3{
  justify-self:center;
  text-align:Center;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.uglyDot{
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color:blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h3>A pretty long word here</h3>
  <div class="uglyDot"></div>
</div>

  <h3>Small word</h3>

<div class="box">
   <h3>Small word</h3>
  <div class="uglyDot"></div>
</div>
```